# как вернуть значения в DataFrame, индексы которых не равны индексу из списка?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, индексация

Код:

```
uniq = df.drop_duplicates(subset='norm').index.values
df.iloc[~uniq, :]
```

Нужно, чтобы из df вернулись те значения, индексы которых не находятся в списке, но этот код возвращает мне таблицу уникальных значений, отсортированную в убывающем порядке по индексу.

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
In [104]: df
Out[104]:
   norm
0     2
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     3

In [105]: uniq = df.drop_duplicates(subset='norm').index

In [109]: res = df.loc[~df.index.isin(uniq)]

In [110]: res
Out[110]:
   norm
2     1
3     2
```

Но можно это сделать проще, воспользовавшись [DataFrame.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
In [112]: df.loc[df.duplicated(subset="norm")]
Out[112]:
   norm
2     1
3     2
```

Comment: Интересно, а кто "минус"-то поставил?

Comment: @strawdog, мне тоже интересно)